# Let $X$ be the union of the standard unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, a circle and two line segments. Find the homology groups of $X$.

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be the subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that is the union of the standard unit sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$, the circle $\{(x,y,0) \mid x^2+y^2= \frac14\}$ and the two line segments $\{(x,0,0)  \mid \frac12 \le x \le1\}$ and $\{(x,0,0) \mid -1\le x\le -\frac12 \}$. Use a Mayer-Vietoris sequence to calculate the homology groups of $X$.

I'm having trouble figuring out what the cover $U \cup V$ should be for $X$. I don't think we can take the usual one where the intersection will be homotopy equivalent to $S^1$ in this case as we have the inner circle and the two line segments also in our space. Can we modify that cover in some way to take into account the additional data? If I take that one and union with the circle and line segments would that work in this case?

Comment: The object of choosing $U$ and $V$ is not to make $U \cap V$ be homotopy equivalent to $S^1$. The object, instead, is to choose them to make $U$, and $V$, and $U \cap V$, each be homotopy equivalent to ***something*** that you already understand.

Comment: This space should be homotopically equivalent to a CW complex $Y$ with one $0$-cell $Y_0$, two $1$-cells attached to $Y_0$, and one $2$-cell attached directly to $Y_0$. Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's establish some notation.

- $S^2$ is the standard unit sphere, $\{ (x,y,z) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 + z^2 \}$.
- $S^1$ is the circle $\{(x, y, 0) \in \mathbb R^3 : x^2 + y^2 = \tfrac 1 4\}$.
- $L_1$ is the *open* line segment $\{(x, 0, 0) \in \mathbb R^3 : \tfrac 1 2 < x 
  < 1\}$.
- $L_2$ is the *open* line segment $\{(x, 0, 0) \in \mathbb R^3 : -1 < x < -\tfrac 1 2\}$.

I suggest we pick the following open cover.
$$ U = S^2 \cup L_1 \cup L_2, \qquad  V = S^1 \cup L_1 \cup L_2.$$

Then

- $U$ deformation retracts onto the $S^2$.
- $V$ deformation retracts onto the $S^1$.
- $U \cap V$ is $L_1 \cup L_2$, which deformation retracts onto the set $\{ (-\tfrac 3 4, 0, 0), (0, 0, \tfrac 3 4) \}$ - a set of two points.

So it is easy to compute the (reduced) homology groups for $U$, $V$ and $U \cap V$.

Having computed the (reduced) homology groups for $U$, $V$ and $U \cap V$, you can then use the Mayer-Vietoris sequence to determine the (reduced) homology groups for $X = U \cup V$.

The overall thought process is a perfect example of what Lee describes in his comment. We're picking $U$ and $V$ so that $U$, $V$ and $U \cap V$ are all homotopy equivalent to spaces whose homology groups are easy to determine.

---

**Edit:** To explain the use of reduced homology, and to spell out the argument used to determine $H_1(X)$ (see comments below).

It seems like we agree that the reduced homology groups of $U$, $V$ and $U \cap V$ are
$$ \widetilde H_n(U) = \begin{cases} \mathbb Z & \text{if }n = 2 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$$ \widetilde H_n(V) = \begin{cases} \mathbb Z & \text{if }n = 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
$$ \widetilde H_n(U \cap V) = \begin{cases} \mathbb Z & \text{if }n = 0 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$

The Mayer-Vietoris sequence contains portions like
$$ \dots \to 0 \to \widetilde H_n(X) \to 0 \dots$$
for all $n \geq 3$, which tells us that $\widetilde H_n(X) = 0$ for $n \geq 3$.

The Mayer-Vietoris sequence also contains the terms
$$ \dots \to 0 \to \mathbb Z \to \widetilde H_2(X) \to 0 \to \dots , $$
which tell us that $\widetilde H_2(X) = \mathbb Z$.

Furthermore, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence contains the terms
$$ \dots \to 0 \to \mathbb Z \to \widetilde H_1(X) \to \mathbb Z \to 0 \to \dots .$$
$\mathbb Z$ is a projective $\mathbb Z$-module, so this short exact sequence splits. Thus $\widetilde H_1(X) = \mathbb Z^{\oplus 2}$.

Finally, the Mayer-Vietoris sequence contains the terms
$$ \dots \to 0 \to \widetilde H_0(X) \to 0,$$
which tell us that $\widetilde H_0(X) = 0$. Of course, this is obviously true, since $X$ is path-connected.

Note that using reduced homology made the Mayer-Vietoris sequence a lot simpler when it came to calculating $\widetilde H_1(X)$ and $\widetilde H_0(X)$. If we had used non-reduced homology, then we would instead have got
$$ \dots \to 0 \to \mathbb Z \to H_1(X) \to \mathbb Z^{\oplus 2} \to \mathbb Z^{\oplus 2} \to H_0(X) \to 0.$$
It is more difficult to read off $H_1(X)$ and $H_0(X)$ from this sequence.

Comment: The space is connected so $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ right? @kenny-wong

Comment: @Sehat Yes, $X$ is path connected so $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb Z$! And therefore, the reduced zeroth homology is $\widetilde H_0(X) \cong 0$. (I strongly recommend you work with reduced homology!) How much progress have you made?

Comment: I think I've managed to conclude that $H_0(X) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ and $H_1(X)$ has dimension $2$ so $H_1(X) \cong \mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z}$. Doesn't the reduced homology argee with the usual one except at $n = 0$? @kenny-wong

Comment: @Sehat That's correct. And you should have $H_2(X) \cong \mathbb Z$ too. Yes, reduced homology agrees with the usual one except at $n = 0$; reduced homology makes this Mayer-Vietoris sequence much more tractable.

Comment: For $n \ge 3$ I think we end up with $H_n(X) \cong 0$ as the terms $H_n(A) \oplus H_n(B)$ will result in $0$ as well as the two point set $A \cap B$? I'm not sure what is the use of the reduced one here, where does it help? @kenny-wong

Comment: Yes, $H_n(X) \cong 0$ for $n \geq 3$.

Comment: @Sehat I edited my answer to provide more details. In particular, (i) I explained why reduced homology makes the Mayer-Vietoris sequence more tractible, and (ii) I spelled out the logic for determining $H_1(X)$ (which we didn't really nail in this discussion).

Comment: Are you sure this argument works? How can you be sure that $H_1(X)$ isn't something like $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z_2$?